# How to kill EnterFrame within function in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

how to  remove my EventListener with my actionscript 3 like this, i have tried any code, but i still can't kill my EventListener, please help a newbie one....

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, fl_SwipeToGoToNextPreviousFrame);

function fl_SwipeToGoToNextPreviousFrame(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
    if (event.offsetX == -1)
    {
        // swiped left
        nextFrame,play();
    }

    else if (event.offsetX == 1)
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler_2);

        function fl_EnterFrameHandler_2(event:Event):void
        {
            prevFrame();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always put in function line :

```
function eventHandler (event:Event):void {
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type , arguments.callee);
}
```

And this will remove event from inside handler function .

Answer (score 1):

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler_2);
```

should `removeEventListener` do it

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be unable to resolve the `fl_EnterFrameHandler_2` function name from somewhere outside. Place its code outside of the brackets that delimit swipe listener function:

```
function fl_SwipeToGoToNextPreviousFrame(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
    if (event.offsetX == -1)
    {
        // swiped left
        nextFrame,play();
    }

    else if (event.offsetX == 1)
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler_2);
    }
}

function fl_EnterFrameHandler_2(event:Event):void
{
    prevFrame();
}
```

Like this. With this, you would be able to invoke `removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler_2);` from elsewhere.

Comment: Hey, thanks for help... its code running well... now i will develop the "carousel" effect with this... nice share...